# How to use Show in case one of the graphics doesn't exist?

Tags: graphics

I tried to combine three and more graphics with the `Show` command; but sometimes there is no data, so some of the graphics are empty lists.
I tried this:

```
Show[ grPacing, grAcq, If[grNewMap !={}, grNewMap] ... ]
```

But there are a lot of errors.

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Liad.

Answer (score 7):

`Show` has no problem with empty lists:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}];
p2 = Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}];

Show[p1, p2, {}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The problem you are seing is that `If[False,x]` returns `Null`, so you end up with `Show[plot1,plot2,Null]`

Here's a way around that:

```
grPacing = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}];
grAcq = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}];
grNewMap = {};
Show[grPacing, grAcq,If[grNewMap =!= {}, grNewMap, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]]
```

You could also use a wrapper that removes everything that's not a `Graphics` or an option:

```
ShowValidOnly[a___] := Show@@Cases[{a}, (_Graphics | _Rule | _RuleDelayed)]
ShowValidOnly[grPacing, grAcq, grNewMap]
```

Comment: Is there a reason one would not simply use `Show[p1, p2, {}]`?  What am I missing?  Also, you could replace `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]` with `##&[]`.

Comment: I understand.Thank you all!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's great for cases where your plot function will return either a valid graphics or `{}`, but in the general case it's nice to be able to perform an arbitrary check. Though you could replace `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]` with `{}`. That's just my personal preference.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use `DeleteCases`. In this example, where you wish to remove `Null`, you could use

```
 Show[  ...   DeleteCases[ graphicStuff , Null]   ... ]
```

and then `Show` will be happy.